# Geo Charts in Emails | Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id | Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets' spreadsheet with the following data:

[image]

I have used the data above to create a geo chart (I did this by following the steps: "Insert chart" -> select one option from "maps" in dropdown). The geochart I created is shown below:

[image]

I want to get a daily email that contains a png version of this map. I have used the following script in google app scripts to do so:

```
​function myFunction() {
  // get references to the sheet and the charts
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();

  // set up some variables for our email
  const chartBlobs = new Array();
  const emailImages = {};
  var titles = ["<h1>Geographical Distribution</h1><br>"]
  let emailBody = "<br>";

  // iterate for each loaded chart
  var counter = 0
  charts.forEach(function(chart,i){ // this is line 14
    chartBlobs[i] = chart.getAs("image/png"); // this is line 15
    emailBody += titles[i]+"<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+i+"'></p>"; // Aligning the chart to the center of the body in the email
    emailImages["chart"+i] = chartBlobs[i];
    counter++;
  });

  // send email
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "some_email@gmail.com",
    subject:"trial",
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages: emailImages
  })

 }
```

However, when I run the script, I get the following error:

[image]

Note that I commented, in the script, where lines 14 and 15 are. I have covered the id of the document I used for privacy reasons

**This error only appears when I use a Geo Chart. This error does not appear when I use any other chart.**

**What would you recommend I do to fix this error?**

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your error message, I thought that when Google Slides is used, your issue might be able to be removed. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  const chartBlobs = new Array();
  const emailImages = {};
  var titles = ["<h1>Geographical Distribution</h1><br>"]
  let emailBody = "<br>";
  var counter = 0

  const temp = SlidesApp.create("temp"); // Added
  const temps = temp.getSlides()[0]; // Added

  charts.forEach(function (chart, i) {

    chartBlobs[i] = temps.insertSheetsChartAsImage(chart).getBlob(); // Modified

    emailBody += titles[i] + "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart" + i + "'></p>";
    emailImages["chart" + i] = chartBlobs[i];
    counter++;
  });
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "some_email@gmail.com",
    subject: "trial",
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages: emailImages
  });

  DriveApp.getFileById(temp.getId()).setTrashed(true); // Added
}
```

- When this script is run, the chart is inserted to Google Slides. And, the image blob is retrieved from the chart on Google Slides.

#### Note:

- From [Daniel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73491809/geo-charts-in-emails-service-spreadsheets-failed-while-accessing-document-with/73494691?noredirect=1#comment129787134_73494691)

  > To elaborate a bit more, using Slides as intermediary is a workaround. The cause of the error seems to be a bug that affects some chart types. It can be found in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182701055).

#### Reference:

- [insertSheetsChartAsImage(sourceChart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertsheetschartasimagesourcechart)

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, using Slides as intermediary is a workaround. The cause of the error seems to be a bug that affects some chart types. It can be found in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182701055).

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for your additional information. I thought that your comment will be useful for users. So, I added your comment at "Note" section.